# page configured incorrectly?

Tags: php, android, json

I moved my files from my `Xampp` server over to a live server and now the `PHP` doesn't seem to be working correctly. This file is the problem

```
<?php

require ("../Android/connect.php");
require ("../Android/queries.php");

if ($query_run = mysql_query($questions_query)) {
    if (mysql_num_rows($query_run) == NULL) {       
        $response["success"] = 0;         
        echo json_encode($response);

    } else {            
        $response ['questions'] = array();      
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
            $info = array();
            $info ['display_name'] = $row['display_name'];
            $info ['field_type'] = $row['field_type'];
            $info ['option_value'] = $row['option_value'];          

            array_push($response["questions"], $info);          
        }
        // success
        $response["success"] = 1; 
        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
?>
```

My `Android` app that was getting `JSON` from this file now gets null `JSONObjects`. When I open it in my browser it gives me this error:

"**Server error**
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://mysite.com/Android/myfile.php. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly."

My first thought was my `connect.php` or `queries.php` that are included were at fault. However they work fine. I can get them to display in my browser or echo out messages to me. The file above however will not work. Anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @Nile ok thanks, do you have anything to offer about the current problem though?

Comment: Can you tell if it's a problem with interacting with the database? Try adding some `or die(mysql_error())`s

Comment: Try commenting out the lower portion of your code and seeing if the page loads with just the requires. This sounds like a php config error.

Comment: @Nile Well in order to get here I have to login, and by doing that I use the same connect.php file included here. There is definitely an active connection to the server/db. I could not get here in my app if there was not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($query_run = mysql_query($questions_query)) {
```

Be sure to define $questions_query- looks like that's your problem right there

Comment: questions query is defined in queries.php which is included. I also tried your solution of commenting out everything below the required files. I get the same error

Comment: And after that did you try commenting out EVERYTHING? If the page loads with a blank script, then one of your included files are screwing it up. Are you opening either of those files with the php short tag <?   ...? (instead of <?php)

Comment: If it still doesn't load then your PHP config is off.

Comment: I got it, I needed to change `require` to `require_once` on the connection.php. Odd, but it worked

Comment: Yep- for future reference that's a good quick way to quickly ID problems. If you don't immediately know where a problem is coming from, comment out all your new code at once and then gradually add it back in one piece at a time. Cheers!